# How can I add a single quote to a VBA string used as a search and replace string in a formula?

Tags: string, vba, excel

How can I add a single quote to a VBA string used as a search and replace string in a formula?  I have the following code:

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim fnd1 As Variant
Dim rplc1 As Variant
Dim fnd2 As Variant
Dim rplc2 As Variant

fnd1 = "Instructions!"
rplc1 = "Info!"
fnd2 = "#REF!$A$7:$F$2000"
rplc2 = "INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(" '","Info!G2","'","!a:f"),1)"- this is the issue line

For Each sht1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
sht1.Cells.replace What:=fnd1, Replacement:=rplc1, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

sht1.Cells.replace What:=fnd2, Replacement:=rplc2, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Next sht1
```

`

The rplc2 replacement string will not work because I cannot get the single quote needed to reference another worksheet to be part of the replacement string.  I can not figure out how to add the single quote needed for a sheet reference in the concatenate formula.  I tried:

```
rplc2 = "INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(char(34),"Info!G2",char(34),"!a:f"),1)"
```

But this doesn't work either.  I also tried several other methods but I can get a combination that works.

Comment: `"INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("" '"",""Info!G2"",""'"",""!a:f""),1)"` all single `"`   needs to be double `""`

Comment: Thank you Scott and Neechalkaran . Neither of these methods worked. When you try to use this, it doesn't work as part of a concatenate function nor does it work when typed in to a formula. I cannot get this concatenate to work when it is referencing and other cell in another sheet to get the sheet name that the Vlookup command is trying to use.  Since the sheet being referenced can change I am trying to pull the current sheet name from a cell in the Info sheet that contains the selected sheet name. That is not even addressing the problem of updating this formula in a macro.

Comment: This is the formula I am currently updating using code but it does not work. 
=IFERROR(INDEX(F48:Q48,1,$S$10)-VLOOKUP(LEFT(D48,13),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'","I‌​nfo!G2","'","!a:f"),1),6,FALSE),0) 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Then your indirest part should be `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""'"",Info!G2,""'"",""!a:f"")`

Comment: - I resolved the problem using Scott's double quotes method.  I had tried that but it turns out that wasn't the problem.  My formula was incorrect because I needed to use the Indirect inside of a concatenate with another concatenate. The replacement formula that worked was:        rplc2 = "INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""'"",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""'"",""Info"",""'"",""!G2""),1),""'"",""!A:F""),1)"

Answer (score 0):

you can use only escaped special characters within double quote.
to escape double quote you can use either two double quote or ChrW(34)
to escape single quote you can use ChrW(39)
in above case

"INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(" & ChrW(34) & " '" & ChrW(34) & "," & ChrW(34) & "Info!G2" & ChrW(34) & "," & ChrW(34) & "'" & ChrW(34) & "," & ChrW(34) & "!a:f" & ChrW(34) & "),1)"

or

"INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("" '"",""Info!G2"",""'"",""!a:f""),1)" ' all single " needs to be double ""

Comment: I believe the "ChrW(39)" (in your first paragraph) is a typo  for "ChrW(34)".  (I'd edit your answer, but I'm not 100% sure whether I should - perhaps Excel accepts an apostrophe as an acceptable alternative to a quotation mark - in which case it might not be a typo.)

Answer (score 0):

" marks in strings can get confusing. Most of the time when you want a single " mark it is to bracket a word such as "test". When you have it correct in a string it will actually look like this: ""test"", but when the string is used the actual string data is: "test", the outside " marks get stripped off.